# HttpRequest.getParameter("...") doesn't return value in doFilter method

Tags: jsp, servlets

request.getParamter() method should return type param value but it returns null value instead.

```
@Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
           throws IOException, ServletException {

       HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
       HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

       String action = req.getParameter("type");

       if(action != null && controllerMapping.containsKey(action)) {
           config.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(controllerMapping.get(action)).forward(req, resp);
       }
       else {
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
   }
```

The calling page is here:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Add an Athlete</title>
        <link href="<c:url value='/css/main.css' />" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="add_athlete">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> Athlete Information </legend>
                <form class="add_athlete" action="<c:url value='/' />" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add_athlete" />
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name" required="required"/>
                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required="required"/>
                    <label>Age:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age" required="required" />
                    <label>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required="required" />
                    <label>Image:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" required="required" /><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I use type param in doPost() method of servlet it works correctly, but when this request is forwarded to doFilter() method of servlet, I receive NullPointerException. Is it because of POST method? 
I don't understand why it doesn't work, can anybody help me to deal with it?

Comment: are you getting Exception after submitting the form?

Comment: "I receive NullPointerException". Where?? Clarify the exact issue

Comment: @ArunKumar I receive NullPointerException

Comment: getting  exception    when?

Comment: when I submit the form getting NullPointerException and it is because of the code String action = req.getParameter("type") as req.getParameter("type") returns null.

Comment: of course after adding the null check if(action != null) there is no NPE.  But I don't understand why req.getParameter("type") returns null.